# Разделение числа на разряды в Java

Tags: java, числа, форматирование

Есть условная переменная Int. Её нужно изменить так, чтобы оно выдавало не просто число "3434436", а "3,434,436". Уже пробовал через regex. Может я что-то не так делаю.

Comment: Выложите свою попытку решить задачу, даже если она не правильно работает. И опишите конкретную проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

```
int value = 3434436;
String str = String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", value);
```

`,` Запятая - это разделитель групп. В зависимости от указанной локализации может оказаться вообще не запятой.

Answer (score 1):

```
int myInt = 3434436;
//дефолтный форматтер для текущей локали
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols(); 
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\''); //разделитель тысяч '
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(myInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

ну или так)

```
   public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 3434436;
        System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%,d", number);
    }

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]